# File system is reported full with half of it use by ecrypt and other half by the /home/user

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage, ecryptfs

I install my workstation using the installer provided option to encrypt my "/home" directory, I expected it to be completly transparent on usage but after the system warn me that the filesystem was full I discovered that half of the space was reported as used by "ecrypt" file while the other half was used by "/home/username" directory.

I did read about the fact that the /home/user is a virtual mount of the *real* data in .ecrypt and should not take any more space on the harddrive.

However my system (ubuntu 16.04) doesn't seem to understand it that way and makes me unable to fully use my hardrive.

"df" report a size for the /home partition of 226G, which "du" affirmed is half filled with /home/user and half filled with the .ecrypt part.

Other utilities that make sytem call for checking filesytem are encountering the same issue, for example python os.statvfs('/home/') is showing result coherent with "du".

If eCrypt doesn't "double" the space used for the /home folder how do I help the system understand it ? 
If my hardrive is indeed full how do I make correct use of eCrypt so it didn't double the space needed for my /home data ?

below the exact result of previously discussed commands :

system info :

```
$> uname -a
Linux pc-name 4.15.0-43-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 7 13:31:08 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

df result :

```
$> df -h

udev 3,9G 0 3,9G 0% /dev
tmpfs 787M 9,5M 778M 2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 226G 199G 16G 93% /
tmpfs 3,9G 71M 3,8G 2% /dev/shm
tmpfs 5,0M 4,0K 5,0M 1% /run/lock
tmpfs 3,9G 0 3,9G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2 473M 121M 328M 27% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1 511M 3,5M 508M 1% /boot/efi
tmpfs 787M 36K 787M 1% /run/user/1000
/home/username/.Private 226G 199G 16G 93% /home/username
```

result from lsblk :

```
$>sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME                  FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
nvme0n1                           238,5G            
├─nvme0n1p3           LVM2_member 237,5G            
│ ├─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 swap          7,9G            
│ │ └─cryptswap1      swap          7,9G [SWAP]     
│ └─ubuntu--vg-root   ext4        229,6G /          
├─nvme0n1p1           vfat          512M /boot/efi  
└─nvme0n1p2           ext2          488M /boot
```

du result :

```
$> sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /home/
119G /home/username
119G /home/.ecryptfs
237G /home/
```

Python viewpoint :

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> statvfs = os.statvfs('/home/')
>>> statvfs.f_frsize * statvfs.f_blocks
242521694208
#that is 242G of hardrive
>>> statvfs.f_frsize * statvfs.f_bfree
29071433728
>>> statvfs.f_frsize * statvfs.f_bavail
16728436736
#16G of free space
```

Any help to solve or diagnostic the problem further such as tool to inspect actual disk usage is welcome.

-- Edit adding df information while user is not log in :

```
Sys. de fichiers            Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
udev                          3,9G       0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                         787M    9,5M  778M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root   226G    201G   14G  94% /
tmpfs                         3,9G    252K  3,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5,0M    4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         3,9G       0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2                473M    121M  328M  27% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                511M    3,5M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                         787M    120K  787M   1% /run/user/1002
```

Comment: Check all the same tools when your user is *not* logged in. When you're logged it it appears that /home/youruser takes up a lot of space. (As long as you don't have the rare bug where logging out doesn't unmount your encrypted home, but it should've been fixed... logging in with a different user immediately after booting would completely avoid it though). I guess you've already seen https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092277/what-is-home-ecryptfs-and-why-does-it-take-up-so-much-space/1092902 ? Also, have you run out of space or hit errors when the hopefully doubled size exceeds the disk space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the advice from Xen2050 I found the root of my problems. When the error occur the "doubled" sized did exceed the disk space, the disc is thus not full due to eCrypt virtual mounting (as expected). After investigation it appear that the disk is effectively used by the /home partition on one hand (~120G) but also by the /var/lib which contain 62G of docker libs ...

The initial misconsception came from the output of df for the user using eCrypt which show :

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 226G 199G 16G 93% /
/home/username/.Private     226G 199G 16G 93% /home/username
```

leading me to beleive that all the space was eaten by the /home/username partition